# Как прописать правила в .htaccess для домена 3-го уровня?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Добрый день.

Имеется домен 2-го уровня domain.com. Если к нему конектиться с любым адресом 3-го уровня, т.е. на test.domain.com, он открывает сайт domain.com. Как можно прописать правила в .htaccess, чтобы при входе, например, sss.domain.com, сайт обрабатывал данные с get запросом, например, ?site=sss.

Comment: Был уже где-то подобный вопрос в недрах ХэшКода с весьма позновательными ответами. Попробуйте, вдруг понравится?

Comment: Он определяет, но перед в конце запроса ставить "."(точку) я понял, что это с домена он так парсирует, но как от этого избавиться прям в htaccess-e? вот сам код:
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-zA-Z]+\.)?delux\.tj
 RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?name=%1 [L]

Comment: Опять 25... уже 4 раз этот порос вижу.... поиском не пользуются, обленились совсем.

Comment: Ты читать можешь? Я нашел по поиску, но их способ в значении добавляет в конце точку, есть другой?

Comment: Хоть и устарело! только .htaccess-ом не обойтись!!!!!!!!!!!! тут надо еще добавлять записи в настройки bind-а.

Comment: @Ёхарный Бабай, если на домен прописана запись *.domain.com, то bind как бы не нужен.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

А почему бы не сделать всё это на уровне приложения ?

где то в конфиге (пример на php):

```
$d = explode('.', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
if(count($d) == 3) { // домен 3-го уровня
    define('SITE', $d[0]);
} else {
    define('SITE', '');
}
```

и место:

```
if (!empty($_GET['site'])) {
    ...
}
```

использовать:

```
if (!empty(SITE)) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: А как вы будете направлять домен третьего уровня на ваш сервер??

Для того чтобы направить домен my.mydomain.com нужна запись типа А на поддомен в bind-е и запись об DocumentRoot в настройках Apache.

Comment: А вы читали вопрос ? :)

>> Если к нему конектиться с любым адресом 3-го уровня, т.е. на test.domain.com, он открывает сайт domain.com

Answer (score 0):

Я делал так:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mysite.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mysite\.com(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?domainname=%1%2 [L,QSA]
```